# Google Chrome form submission with onclick events

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, onclick

I have a small issue with my submission button in my form.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Uploading...';return true;" value="Upload" />
```

I disable the button and display some text to let the user know that their upload is being processed. Note that I also *return true* to inform Chrome that I still want to submit the form after execution.

However, despite returning true, Google Chrome will not submit this form unless I remove the `onclick` event entirely.

Do I have to put it all in a function in some embedded script elsewhere on the page and only call the function in the `onclick` event?

Comment: because you disable the button, the form will not submit.

Comment: This is true; is there a way to disable the button without disabling the form to prevent multiple submissions from impatient users?

Comment: "var t=this; setTimeout(function(){t.disabled=true;},100);  ... "